# Error while trying to send email using PHPMAILER

Tags: php

SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

```
if(empty($errors)) {
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->Username = 'o.rostom.93@gmail.com';
        $mail->Password = 'XXXXXX'; 
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mail->Port = 465;
        $mail->FromName = $fields['fname'] . ' ' . $fields['lname'];
        $mail->addAddress('o.rostom.93@hotmail.com','Omar Khairy');
        $mail->Body = $fields['message'];
        if(!$mail->Send()) {
           echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo "NON";
        }
    }
```

I have tried manuplating ports, SMTP Secures, nothing is getting better, I have enabled POP and Imap from the gmail, I have also turned on less secure apps, nothing, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";              
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port       = 587;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure gmail is blocking connection from App, you can turn off this feature: log in your account and paste this link [link](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)